# React button hover css pseudoclass not working

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am making a todo app using react and faunadb. In the main UI there is a button which when hovered on I want to change cursor to pointer. This is the button JSX:

```
<button className="add-btn"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus}/></button>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.add-btn:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Omit `:hover`, simply declare

```
.add-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button className="btn hover"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus}/></button>
```

add css

```
.hover:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```